# Is there any equivalent to the Perl regexes' \K backslash sequence in Python?

Tags: python, regex, perl

Perl's regular expressions have the [`\K`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Misc) backslash sequence:

> **\K**
>   This appeared in perl 5.10.0. Anything matched left of `\K` is not
>   included in `$&`, and will not be replaced if the pattern is used in a
>   substitution. This lets you write `s/PAT1 \K PAT2/REPL/x` instead of
>   `s/(PAT1) PAT2/${1}REPL/x` or `s/(?<=PAT1) PAT2/REPL/x`.
>
> Mnemonic: *Keep*.

Is there anything equivalent in Python?

Comment: Python (`regex` module) also supports it.

Comment: @revo, are you adding an answer to that effect (presumably with a link to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex and/or https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex), or shall I?

Comment: (...also pertinent, https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/issues/151/request-k -- the ticket for `\K` being added to the regex module).

Comment: You can simulate `\K` on simple cases with lookbehinds as well it all depends on your pattern. @CharlesDuffy go ahead.

Comment: @revo "You can simulate \K on simple cases with lookbehinds" That's already mentioned in the docs that eugene quoted.

Comment: And I didn't read that quote entirely. @ThisSuitIsBlackNot

Comment: Note also that the method `re.findall` returns only capturing groups and not the whole match: `re.findall('I need (that)', s)` => `['that']`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The proposed replacement to the Python `re` module, [available from `pypi` under the name `regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), has this feature. Its canonical source repository and bug tracker are [in bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex).

This was added in late 2015, in [ticket 151](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/issues/151/request-k); taking an example of its use from that ticket:

> ```
> import regex as mrab
> >>> bsk = mrab.compile(r'start=>\K.*')
> >>> print(bsk.search('boring stuff start=>interesting stuff'))
> <regex.Match object; span=(20, 37), match='interesting stuff'>
> ```