# Regex to match string if NOT only string on line

Tags: regex

I want to match nvalue if it's NOT the only string on a line.

```
nvalue : should not match
This nvalue : should match
Nvalue example : should match
```

I know the regex to match nvalue if it's the only string:

```
^\bnvalue\b$
```

but I don't know how to turn it around.

Comment: Just a remark: To match `nvalue` if it is the complete string, you don't need `\b` like in your example. `^nvalue$` is enough and simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative lookbehind:

```
 ^(?!nvalue$).*nvalue
```

Here `^(?!nvalue$)` means match beginning of a string only is it is not followed by `nvalue` and end of string `$` immediately after that.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/1vOhQt/1

**Update**

If you need to extract the `nvalue` only, wrap it into a capture group using parenthesis:

```
^(?!nvalue$).*(nvalue)
```

The result will be stored in the first match group. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/1vOhQt/3.

If you're using PCRE flavour, use `\K` to reset any previously matched subpattern:

```
^(?!nvalue$).*\Knvalue
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/1vOhQt/2

In Python the `\K` is [supported in `regex` module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39664218/4295017).

Comment: Thanks. I noticed in the demo that "This" is also included in the match. How can I get rid of it? Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm new to regex.

Comment: @Hermie: Please see update. There may be other options depending on your regex flavour. What it the flavour?

Comment: Flavour is Python. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, so with word boundaries included: `^(?!nvalue$).*(\bnvalue\b)` Demo: https://regex101.com/r/1vOhQt/4

Answer (score 1):

You can use **match-group** and operator `|` as alternation to match both possibilities:

## [`((\w+ nvalue)|(nvalue \w+)`)](https://regex101.com/r/uEwIo8/5)

and it works on all regex-search-engine

with flags `g` : global
............... `i` : case-sensitive
................`m` : multi-line

or:

## `((\w+ [Na]value)|([Na]value \w+))`