# Ignoring prefix if it exists for regex match, then continue matching

Tags: regex

I want to match the first 1 to 3 characters of set `[A-Z]`, but I want to ignore the prefix `XYZ_`.

Example:

- XYZ_**ABC**1234
- XYZ_**DEF**1234
- **DEF**0000A0
- **D**00A0
- **BCD**A1
- **CDE**

I'm trying to use a negative lookahead of the form `^(?!XYZ_)?[A-Z]{1,3}`. However, this will return 'XYZ' from the first two examples (works fine for the other examples). I.e. its output is:

- **XYZ**_ABC1234
- **XYZ**_DEF1234
- **DEF**0000A0
- **D**00A0
- **BCD**A1
- **CDE**

How can I ignore a prefix (if it exists) from a string and match on the condition I'm looking for after it?

Comment: What about `XYZ_ABCD1234` and `XYZ_ACB1234`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland You would extract ABC and ACB, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is somewhat Python specific to the `re` module.

I was able to achieve my desired outcome using `\K` which resets the starting point of the reported match.

As such, if using the Perl Compatible Regex Expression (PCRE), the answer is: `^(?:XYZ_\K)?[A-Z]{1,3}`

[More can be read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664058/is-there-any-equivalent-to-the-perl-regexes-k-backslash-sequence-in-python)

Comment: Why is `XYZ_` hardwired in your regex?

Comment: @CarySwoveland It was an example prefix.